# CUDARuntimeError with Chainer

Tags: cuda, deep-learning, chainer

```
chainer.cuda.available
```

and

```
chainer.cuda.cudnn_enabled
```

both return 'True'.

But when I try

```
    cuda.to_gpu(data, 1)
```

it gives the following error -

```
CUDARuntimeError                          Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-87cf96844cac> in <module>()
----> 1 cuda.to_gpu(data, 1)

/home/shreez/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/chainer/cuda.py in to_gpu(array, device, stream)
192     check_cuda_available()
193     assert stream is None  # TODO(beam2d): FIX IT
--> 194     with get_device(device):
195         dev_id = int(get_device(array))
196         if dev_id != -1 and dev_id != cupy.cuda.device.get_device_id():

cupy/cuda/device.pyx in cupy.cuda.device.Device.__enter__ (cupy/cuda/device.cpp:1503)()

cupy/cuda/device.pyx in cupy.cuda.device.Device.use (cupy/cuda/device.cpp:1753)()

cupy/cuda/runtime.pyx in cupy.cuda.runtime.setDevice (cupy/cuda/runtime.cpp:2428)()

cupy/cuda/runtime.pyx in cupy.cuda.runtime.check_status (cupy/cuda/runtime.cpp:1821)()

CUDARuntimeError: cudaErrorInvalidDevice: invalid device ordinal
```

System information:

I am using nvidia driver version 364.19 with Ubuntu 14.04. Chainer is installed with Anaconda 3, chainer version = 1.8.2

nvcc --version returns the following:

```
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2015 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Tue_Aug_11_14:27:32_CDT_2015
Cuda compilation tools, release 7.5, V7.5.17
```

Answer (score 2):

The error happened as I used gpu 1 instead of 0. Changing

```
cuda.to_gpu(data, 1)
```

to

```
cuda.to_gpu(data, 0)
```

fixes the issue.